# Serialization : Data Tempring in Serializable Creating .ser file

Tags: java, security, serialization

I Write a Serializable Program, first i'm create a '**Test**' class then Serialize the Test Class Object in "**java.ser**" file successfully. When i'm Read the Test class object, When Output is correct. When I open a Serialization generated file "**java.ser**" file, When I changed the some generated Binary Value and again Read this serializable file "**java.ser**" file. Output is totally changed. How ...?

**Test class**

```
package com.test.question;

import java.io.*;

class Test implements Serializable {

    private String name;

    public Test(String name) { this.name = name; }
    public String getName() { return name;}
}
```

**WriteTest Class**

```
package com.test.question;

import java.io.*;

public class WriteTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try (
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("java.ser"));
            ) {

            Test test1 = new Test("OpenJdk-12");
            oos.writeObject(test1);

        } catch (IOException io) {
            io.printStackTrace();
        }
    }   
}
```

**ReadTest Class**

```
package com.test.question;

import java.io.*;

public class ReadTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try (
                ObjectInputStream  ois =  new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("java.ser"))
            ) {

            //Deserilization of test object
            Test test2 = (Test)ois.readObject();

            System.out.println("Name is : " + test2.getName());

        } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException iocnfe ) {
            iocnfe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

**java.ser File**

```
aced 0005 7372 0016 636f 6d2e 7465 7374
2e71 7565 7374 696f 6e2e 5465 7374 6d96
c315 d09c f0eb 0200 014c 0004 6e61 6d65
7400 124c 6a61 7661 2f6c 616e 672f 5374
7269 6e67 3b78 7074 000a 4f70 656e 4a64
6b2d 3132
```

First Run This Program Output.

**Output:**

```
D:\Linux\IDE\All-Workspace\OCA-Wrokspace\Ocaexam\src>java --module-path mods --module testingProgram/com.test.question.ReadTest
Name is : OpenJdk-12
```

And Open A Serialziable generated "**java.ser**" file, when I changed the last value in java.ser file **3132 = 3134**. And **Run again** This program,  output is totally changed.

Second run this Program.

```
D:\Linux\IDE\All-Workspace\OCA-Wrokspace\Ocaexam\src>java --module-path mods --module testingProgram/com.test.question.ReadTest
Name is : OpenJdk-14
```

My Question is Serializable generated file is Secure or not...?

Comment: If you change the contents of a file and read it back in then of course the results will be different. Besides that, serialization doesn't write code to the files but values, that's why deserialization might fail if the structure of a class is different from when the object was serialized. Additionally, standard serialization is _not_ secure in the way you seem to think it should be. You could roll your own serializer and deserializer to add encryption etc. though - or look for a library that does it. An easy way might be to use json and plain text encryption along with some hashes.

Comment: @Thomas JEP 154: Remove Serialization {Could you see this and justify } https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/154

Comment: What's unclear about this? Btw, this is related to serialization performance and stability, not security of the data. And although I'd need to guess why this proposal has been closed I'd say a huge part is that serialization is still being used in a large number of applications (e.g. web servers which serialize sessions to disk). Changing that to something better would have a huge impact and thus Java serialization will probably stay a while - that doesn't say that you can't/shouldn't use anything better if you have the chance to do so.

Comment: @NgSharma JEP 154 was published on April 1st. However, it does seem that Java Serialization is going away. (I've been caught out by this as well.)

Comment: @Thomas I'd suggest avoiding rolling your own encryption.

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline you're absolutely right and using existing standards is much preferable over rolling your own solution, especially where security is concerned.